# Are linux commands (grep, awk etc) part of the system, or the shell?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, awk

I'm a developer, so I know my way around a terminal, but I never really dove into it. I can write bash scripts (albeit on a beginner level, not my area of expertise), but I now need to understand something for my work. I have 2 docker images (alpine with busybox and ash AND ubuntu with bash). Both have awk - one runs gawk and the other mawk, and I need to have the same one running.

**Question:**

Now I started wondering - is gawk/mawk part of **terminal** and/or **shell** OR is it part of **OS**? Not only awk - I guess other commands like grep, echo, man etc, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither really.

Shells contain some builtin commands. These are fairly easy to find with a web search, for example here's [Bash builtin command section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) from [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org) [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents).

`grep`, `awk`, `echo`, `man` etc. aren't builtins, they're executable binaries. While most Linux distributions ship with a version of these, they can't really be called "a part of the OS" in the same sense you'd call executables in %WINDIR% parts of Windows OS. They're just standard tools.

Technically "Linux" isn't an OS, it's just the kernel offering interface between user and hardware. Debian, Ubuntu, Alpine, Gentoo... they're "Linux-based Operating Systems", and what's "part of the OS" depends on the distribution. For example `apt` can be considered a part of Debian-based distros as it's the main SW installation / maintenance tool, but not RedHat-based - the equivalent in that scene is `yum`.

You can find the directory containing the binary with command `which <cmd>` - for example `which grep` returns `/usr/bin/grep`. In general binaries are located in `bin` and `sbin` -subdirectories in `/`, `/usr` and `/usr/local`.

`awk` isn't only a command, it's a complete scripting language, created for pattern searching and text processing. `gawk`, `mawk` or `nawk` (and the original `awk`) are `awk` interpreters. Baeldung has a [nice page explaining the differences](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-nawk-gawk-mawk-difference).

BusyBox is an entirely different kettle of ghoti. It's a multi-call binary which can be used in lieu of a number of different tools and utilities, including `awk`. So if you check what `/usr/bin/awk` actually is in a system running BusyBox, you'll most likely find it's a symlink to `/usr/bin/busybox`.

You can't really compare `busybox awk` with the full GNU `awk`. BusyBox being a kinda Swiss Army Knife it contains only a small subset of the options available with the original binary it's replacing. Besides that, tools and options available with BusyBox depend entirely on the version used. Available functions you'll find in [BusyBox documentation](https://busybox.net/BusyBox.html).

If it's essential that your two systems both use for example `gawk`, you need to ensure it's available on both systems, and ensure that all references to `awk` point to `gawk` instead. If you need the same *version* is running on both, you might need to build from source on at least one of the systems.

Comment: So writing "awk <command>" is similar to writing "python <command>", right? And it is similar to having python v2 or python v3 both being named - awk has different flavors, depending on the one installed, right? And a second question - so awk in a system running Busybox is actually part of busybox and not part of /usr/bin, if I understand you correctly? Just theoretically - I can install Busybox on ubuntu and get the same awk (assuming same version of Busybox)?

Comment: Second first: exactly, except it's not a "part" of BusyBox but its function, and there's nothing theoretical - you can install BusyBox to any Linux distro :-) First second: `python` and `awk` differ in purpose. As `g/m/n/awk` is an executable (~command) in itself, I'd rather express it as `awk <function> file`. In usage it's more limited than Python, but extremely powerful in what it's intended for. Follows the old *NIX way of not having a few tools that do a lot of things, but having a lot of tools, each of which does only one thing but extremely well.

Comment: As far as I understand it, `gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk` all add different functionalities to original `awk`. Consequently I'd expect that while core functionality is the same for each interpreter, you could write a `gawk` script that fails if run with `mawk` due to different options. I depend heavily on `awk` for certain purposes, but I'm nowhere near a power user so my understanding is admittedly a bit shaky on this :-) I think man pages are the best starting point to look deeper.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Peregrino69's answer: most commands like `grep`, `man`,`ls` et cetera are separate programs.

But the shell itself is also a separate program. The shell program (`ash` or `bash` in your case) takes your commands and will try to call the program that you specify. So, if you type `ls` at the prompt, the shell will look in its `PATH` if there is an executable file called `ls` and then execute that program.

What you call "the terminal" is a program too. The program might be `konsole`, `xterm` or a number of other terminal programs. The terminal normally starts your interactive shell, but that is not necessary. Try, for example:

```
xterm -e 'ls ; sleep 3'
```

A terminal, but no interactive shell.

`pstree` will give you a overview of what programs are started. Try

```
pstree $PPID
```

Comment: Had to upvote :-)